# Undefined property: stdClass::$comments laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

So I try to add a section of comment but when I try to use @forelse I have the error "Undefined property stdClass::$comments"

That's my view

```
@forelse ($ad->comments as $comment)
    <div class="card mb-2">
        <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div>
            {{ $comment->content }}
                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <small>Posté le {{ $comment->created_at->format('d/m/Y') }} par <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ $comment->user->name }}</span></small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@empty
    <div class="alert alert-info">Aucun commentaire pour ce annonce</div>
@endforelse
```

My models Comment Model

```
public function commentable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function comments() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable')->latest();
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

and the other one Ad Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}

public function comments() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable')->latest();
}
```

and finally my controller

```
public function show(Ad $ad) {
    return view('ads.show', compact('ad'));
}
```

Comment: It's saying that `$ads` is a stdClass object, instead of a Ad model. Can you show the function that loads up that view?

Comment: Please add this code block to the edited question (then you can delete the comment).

Comment: That is your `store` function. Can you show your `show` function, since the error is coming from your view? Be sure to [edit] your post and add it there is it's readable

Comment: I just add it but my show function doesnt come from the same controller

Comment: `return redirect()->route('ads.show', $ad)` should be `return redirect()->route('ads.show', $ad->id)`

Comment: @Pippo it's using route model binding, you can pass either the model or the value of the route binding key.

Comment: What does the route definition look like? There really shouldn't be any way for your view to get passed a generic object without it failing somewhere earlier along the way.

Comment: Either show function should receive Ad data object or Ad ID variable, then fetch Ad object by ID and pass to view('ads.show'). It should then have an associated comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the `comments` is not a field but a function so you need to call it like a function `->comments()`.

you can also define the comments field in the controller :

```
public function show(Ad $ad){
    $ad->comments = $ad->comments();
    return view('ads.show', compact('ad'));
}
```

Comment: That's not how Laravel works

Comment: @miken32 I respectfully disagree, MorphMany relationship requires `$ad->comments()` instead of `$ad->comments` since it's a method, not a property.